# GWT CSSResource

Tags: css, gwt

CSSResource interface

```
public interface AppResources extends ClientBundle {
    public static final AppResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(AppResources.class);

    interface Style extends CssResource {
        String login();
    }

    @Source("css/style.gss")
    Style style();

    @Source("images/logo.png")
    ImageResource logo();
}
```

Styles

```
.login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.login .panel-body {
    text-align: center;
}

.login .loginWrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.login .input-group {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

.login .input-group-addon {
    width: 100px;
}
```

When you try to compile
I have error

> [ERROR] The following non-obfuscated class is present in a strict CssResource: panel-body. Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or use an @external declaration for unobfuscated classes.
>
> [ERROR] The following non-obfuscated class is present in a strict CssResource: input-group-addon. Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or use an @external declaration for unobfuscated classes.
>
> [ERROR] The following non-obfuscated class is present in a strict CssResource: input-group. Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or use an @external declaration for unobfuscated classes.

Yes, the problem can be solved by adding these styles in the interface Style
But I would like to know whether it is possible to apply one parenting style login, and the child would automatically moved up ???

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to make it relevant to your actual problem. There are a zillion questions about CSSResource and your title does not help the rest of us know what your specific problem is.

Comment: You'll also need to clarify your question, I don't know what do you mean by this: _"apply one parenting style login, and the child would automatically moved up "_.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get rid of the compile error, just add an `@external` line with all the classes in your CSS, like this:

```
@external panel-body, loginWrapper, input-group, input-group-addon;
```

That way you're telling GWT: "ignore this classes, I'll take care of them". See [the relevant doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes).

But!
One of the points of using `CSSResource` is so you can do this:

```
myWidget.addClassName(AppResources.INSTANCE.style().panelBody());
myWidget.removeClassName(AppResources.INSTANCE.style().loginWrapper());
```

Instead of this:

```
myWidget.addClassName("panel-body");
myWidget.removeClassName("loginWrapper");
```

The second version is more error-prone since you're writing class names by hand and you wouldn't know if you did it right until you launched the application (unless your IDE inspected CSS class names and warned you beforehand).

With `CSSResource` you can ideally define a styling interface with all the necessary methods, use them in your Java code and let someone else (designers) take care of supporting the actual CSS file and attributes.
And, since now your Java code only cares about the interface methods, GWT can take your CSS and clean it, minify it and obfuscate it so it can be better managed during compile- and run-time.

These perks come at the price of having to define a method for every single CSS class that you want GWT to manage. If you only have a bunch of classes, you'd be better off adding the methods for them.

Comment: What will work styles if I have to`.login .input-group {} .menu .input-group {}`
Not whether they will overwrite each other or to take the first?